# How does the weapon inventory work for aircraft?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If I currently have, let's say a plasma cannon on my layout for one of my aircraft, and I build another weapon like a fusion lance or something, and I go to put the fusion lance on the aircraft, will the plasma cannon go back into my weapon inventory or will I lose the plasma cannon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weapons for Aircraft in XCOM are just like weapons for Soldiers; you can swap them out as many times as you like (though why would you?).

Installing weapons takes time (24 hours, I believe), but uninstalling weapons is instant.

Comment: Yeah I wanna be able to take the fusion lance and put it on my firestorms, and then put the plasma's on my other aircrafts, but I started with firestorms having plasmas.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to the answer above, I believe the ship weapon inventory that you built will be available to all the other hangars in the other continents. Thought its a bit strange that transporting a ship will take 3 days yet installing a weapon onto a ship on another continent will take only 24 hours.

Comment: XCOM Magic! You know how it is...

Comment: haha yea its awesome magic.. :D